# Finding transformation matrix for a coordinate transform

Tags: matrix, tensors, coordinate-transformation, differential-geometry

I have a matrix in two different bases. Suppose they are called $g_{\mu \nu}$ in one basis and $\eta_{ab}$ in the other basis. If the transformation between the bases is represented by $T_{\mu}^{\text{ } a}$ then we can write:

$$\eta_{ab} = g_{\mu \nu} T_{a}^{\text{ } \mu} T_{b}^{\text{ } \nu} $$ In my problem, I know both $\eta_{ab}$ and $g_{\mu \nu}$. How can I solve for $T_{a}^{\text{ } \mu}$ on Mathematica? I tried using `LinearSolve` but I don't think I'm doing it right, since I do not get any output.

EDIT: In response to a comment, this is the code I have tried. I have defined the matrices $\eta , g, T$ as `e,metric, T` respectively.

```
coord = {t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]};
d = r^2 - 2 M r + a^2;
s = r^2 + a^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2;
metric = {{(1 - 2 M r/s), 0, 0, (2 M a r Sin[\[Theta]]^2)/(s^2)}, {0, -(s/d), 0, 0}, {0, 0, -s,  0}, {(2 M a r Sin[\[Theta]]^2)/(s^2), 0, 0, Sin[\[Theta]]^2 (r^2 + a^2 + 2 M a^2 r Sin[\[Theta]]^2/s)}};

e = {{0 , 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, -1, 0}}

LinearSolve[e == T metric T, T]
```

I understand this is obviously incorrect, but I'm quite new to Mathematica and I need some help.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please include copy-paste-able Mathematica code that replicates your problem; i.e., provide a minimal working example. This enables the respondents to provide more focused answers without introducing new artifacts. Please use the `{ }` button on the edit window to format the code.

Comment: Please provide a minimal workingexample. incuding at leat the two matrices

Comment: I've added the matrices.

Comment: That is probably too difficult for Mathematica. Your code is wrong because you have to explicitly define the elements of T and then do T.metric.T. But anyway that seems the wrong approach. Why don't you try e.g diagonalize both metrics and then use the eigenvectors to transform one in the other?